# Regarding Hadoop Security via Kerberos

Tags: hadoop, kerberos

I am trying to learn how Kerberos can be implemented in Hadoop.
I have gone through this doc  https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-4487
I have also gone through Basic Kerberos stuff (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KD2Q-2ToloE)

1) The Apache doc uses the word **"Token"** whereas the general doc over the internet uses the term **"Ticket"**.

Are Token and Ticket same ?

2) The Apache doc also    "DataNodes do not enforce any access control on accesses to its data blocks.

This makes it possible for an unauthorized client to read a data block as
      long as she can supply its block ID. It’s also possible for anyone to write
      arbitrary data blocks to DataNodes."

My thoughts on this:-

I can fetch the block Id from file path using the command:-

```
hadoop@Studio-1555:/opt/hadoop/hadoop-1.0.2/bin$ ./hadoop fsck /hadoop/mapred/system/jobtracker.info -files -blocks
```

FSCK started by hadoop from /127.0.0.1 for path /hadoop/mapred/system/jobtracker.info at Mon Jul 09 06:57:14 EDT 2012
/hadoop/mapred/system/jobtracker.info 4 bytes, 1 block(s):  OK
0. blk_-9148080207111019586_1001 len=4 repl=1

As I was authorized to access this file jobtracker.info, I was able to find its blockID using the above command.
I think that if I add some offset to this block ID and write to that datanode.

How can I explicitly mention the blockID while writing a file to HDFS.(What is the command ?)
Any other way to  write arbitrary data blocks to DataNodes ?

Please tell me if my approach is wrong ?

Comment: Have you found any proper complete way to secure a hadoop cluster ?

Answer (score 3):

> Are Token and Ticket same ?

No. Tickets are issued by Kerberos and then servers in Hadoop (NameNode or JobTracker) issue tokens to provide authentication within the Hadoop cluster.  Hadoop does not rely on Kerberos to authenticate running tasks, for instance, but uses its own tokens that were issued based on the Kerberos tickets.

> The Apache doc also "DataNodes do not enforce any access control on accesses to its data blocks.

I'm guessing you're taking that from the JIRA where access control was provided (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-4359) via BlockAccessTokens.  Assuming this is turned on - which it should be in a secure cluster - one cannot access a block on a datanode without such a token, which is issued by the NameNode after authentication and authorization via Kerberos and HDFS' own file system permissions.

Comment: Thanks Jakob for helping me, For my second question "The Apache doc also says"Datanodes do not................................., when the access control is not turned on. I need to know-- How can I access the Datanode and write data arbitarily ?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I access the Datanode and write data arbitrarily ?

I am not sure what you mean here. Do you mean when the user does not have permission? As Jacob mentioned
you will not get a valid BlockAccessToken unless the user has the permissions to access the Data based on the file system permissions, assuming that you have secure Hadoop cluster.